# Exchange limit and sum in certain conditions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, limits-and-convergence

Let
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(s)$ be a series of analytic functions and suppose it converges on some neighbourhood $V$ of $s=0$ and it converges uniformly on $V\cap\{s \;|\; |s|> \varepsilon \}$ for every $\varepsilon>0$. So it is analytic on the punctured neighbourhood $V-\{0\}$. Suppose $\lim_{s\to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(s)$ exists (and finite).

I am looking for references for conditions (other than uniform convergence in whole $V$) for  which
$
\lim_{s\to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(s) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(0)
$

Thank you.

Comment: Dosnt Cauchys formula with contour a small circle around 0 show that the series converges uniformly in a nbh of 0?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Thank you, NJK.